# Создать элемент листа с картинкой и именем

Tags: java, android

Есть окно приложение которое содержит лист. Нужно, чтобы каждый элемент листа отображался как песня в плеере.
Изображение(альбома) и автор - песня. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создать адаптер для элемента вашего списка

Вот пример такого адаптера:

```
    public class PlayListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();



    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public ListViewPlayersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Track> tracks){
        layoutInflater =  (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.tracks = tracks;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tracks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if(view == null)
        {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_track_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textViewTrackName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewName.setText(tracks.get(position).name());
        ImageView imageViewPic = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPic);

        return view;
    }
}
```

В активити создаем экземпляр адаптера и присваиваем его нашему ListView:

```
PlayListAdapter playListAdapter = new PlayListAdapter(this, tracks);
listViewPlayList.setAdapter(playListAdapter);
```

Также не забудьте создать xml-файл с именем `listview_track_item`. Разметка этого файла - это разметка вашего одного трека в списке.
Его можете делать, как вам угодно :

И про класс самого трека не забудьте(Там должно храниться название и все такое прочее)

Comment: Спасибо, всё здорово,А вот можно было бы ещё узнать как картинку по ссылке подтянуть?